# How to avoid (if possible) equipment damage when mounting a gramophone on a car

Tags: audio, modification, hood

This is a question on the verge of general DIY/engineering and car modification:
I am planning to mount a turntable/[gramophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph) either in my car, or (an even stranger idea I know) on the exterior, i.e. on the car hood (possibly similar to the engines sticking out of the hood (like in the fast'n'furious dodge charger).

I have done some basic research and found pictures of a turntable mounted inside a car similar to the way car radios are placed today, which leads me to believe that in fact it is possible to mount it.

The problem I foresee is that the record may get scratched/destroyed, or the needle may get damaged, when the car is on a bumpy road. I therefore wonder - what are other possible problems with this idea, and how to minimize all (including the "bump" problem). If anyone has any experience with mounting similar non-standard audio equipment then I would also like to hear the problems they encountered. Also, I wonder whether mounting it "sticking out of the hood" or internally would make it different for anything else other than the sound volume and obviously usage comfort

Comment: We had enough issues with the early cd players skipping : a turntable ?? good luck...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Your serious about this? Really? I think even if you *could* get it to stabilize enough not to skip around, which is highly doubtful, you'd figure out really quick what a PITB trying to change an LP out at speed would be.

Comment: I am sure Laurel and Hardy did this in one of their episodes.  See- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jtjo3UtL7E  (1 minute 15 seconds)

Comment: Turntables that could play a 7" record in a car were marketed in the '50s

Comment: @DaveSmith - And how many of those models are available today? Last count: zero. I guess it was a popular option :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of attempts at this in the past with a variety of strategies. As mentioned above, some required custom formats/configurations. The link below discusses some of the issues and solutions (?) the US manufacturers encountered.

European manufacturers also had a parallel experimentation track. I know at least one used a large platter mounted vertically.

The problems I'd assume you'd run into is high stylus pressure to overcome vibration (this would wear out your records fairly quickly) and storing and changing discs.

I think a vertical record player might be a good place to start. They don't use gravity to manage stylus pressure and tracking.

[Highway Hi-Fi](https://www.hagerty.com/articles-videos/articles/2017/12/18/obsolete-car-audio-part-2)